# OSGi Bundle Repositories

Tags: components, osgi, bundles

I am empirically testing OSGi Bundles and their relationships for this I need lots of bundles. 
Making these datasets is a difficult task. I already have Eclipse update (1700 Bundles) sites and Spring Enterprise bundle repository for testing, however I want more, anyone out there got massive amounts of bundles. 
I don't even need the code, just the manifests would be fine.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Google Code Search returns 15800 results for [query 'Bundle-SymbolicName file:MANIFEST.MF'](http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=Bundle-SymbolicName+file%3AMANIFEST.MF). If you find some way to automatically download them and remove duplicates you might get a sizable dataset.

Another similar idea is to find some way to search the [Maven central repository](http://mvnrepository.com/) for artifacts that include OSGi bundle manifest.